# Use entire DIVs as buttons with onchange to refresh content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I don't know how to proceed and need your help!

The goal is to use multiple `<DIV>`:s as a list, the list items are listed from AJAX/SQL. When the user is clicking on one of the `<DIV>`:s it should change the "#main"`<DIV>` to view information about the specific `<DIV>` clicked in the list. Hope you're following.

Right now I've found a script and got it working by using `<form>`, `<select>` and `<option>` as seen in the script below.

But instead of this drop down list, `<select>` I want the `<DIV>` in the list to be the link, as `<a>` or simular so that the content of the "#main" `<div>` is changed without the whole page is refreshing and without the .

If you need any more info please let me know!

AJAX:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form>
  <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this answer that was posted but deleted, so if anyone have the same issue this is the way to go:
[ANSWER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyovQ.png)